# Laplace Equation in Polar Coordinates without $\frac{1}{R} \partial_R$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, change-of-variable

As I was reading a book on queue theory, the author needed to solve $p(V_b, V_a)$ where: $p(V_b, V_a) = \frac{1}{4}p(V_b+1, V_a) + \frac{1}{4}p(V_b, V_a+1) + \frac{1}{4}p(V_b-1, V_a) + \frac{1}{4}p(V_b, V_a-1) $

Using the Taylor Expansion $P(V\pm1) \approx P(V,t) \pm \partial_VP(V,t) + \frac{1}{2} \partial^2_{VV}P(V,t)$, the equation above can be simplified to $(\partial^2_{V_bV_b} + \partial^2_{V_aV_a})p(V_b,V_a) = 0 \text{ with boundary conditions: }p(V_b,0)=1, p(0,V_a)=0$.

To solve this Laplace's equation, the author suggests a change of variables to polar coordinates $(R, \theta)$.
Where $R = \sqrt{V_b^2 + V_a^2}, \text{  } \theta=arctan(\frac{V_b}{V_a})$.

The author however asserts that the Laplace's Equation above becomes: $(\partial^2_{RR} + \frac{1}{R^2}\partial^2_{\theta\theta})p(R,\theta) = 0$.

I am extremely confused as to why the author ignored the $\frac{1}{R}\partial_R$ in the Laplace equation above. Shouldn't the Laplace's Equation in polar coordinates be $(\partial^2_{RR} + \frac{1}{R}\partial_R + \frac{1}{R^2}\partial^2_{\theta\theta})p(R,\theta) = 0$ by definition?

Any help is extremely appreciated!

**P.S. Added the original text below:**
[image: Text from book]

Comment: Is $R$ large in the region of interest? Just in general I don't fully understand the boundary conditions and geometry.

Comment: @Ian R is not large. The basic idea here is the race to zero between two queues $V_b, V_a$. From the main equation, each queue can have a single addition or deletion with equal probability. The function p returns the probability that queue $V_a$ hits 0 before $V_b$ hence, $p(V_b = 0, V_a \neq 0) = 0$ and $p(V_b \neq 0, V_a = 0) =1$. Does this help? Is there anything I can further clarify? Thanks.

Comment: So is the domain the whole first quadrant?

Comment: @Ian Yes, the domain is the whole first quadrant. I tried to make some clarifying edits in the question. Let me know if there is anything else that I can further clarify.

Comment: @Ian I have attached an image from the book for more information.

Comment: You're right, this is just not correct. The solution being only $\theta$-dependent is correct, though.

Comment: @Ian why do you say that the solution being only $\theta$ - dependent is correct regardless of the correct Laplace Equation? Feel free to write up the reply as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, note that a solution that is only $\theta$-dependent exists, then note that in 2D even in an unbounded domain the Dirichlet problem has unique solutions. If you don't know that then this problem becomes more complicated, you need to figure out the Green's function for the quadrant, etc.

Comment: Well sorry, you can do it if you know the Green's function for the half plane, because you can see that this solution can be extended to the 2nd quadrant by odd reflection through the $y$ axis. Still, it's nontrivial.